# Optimizing query response time

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a live, filterable report in my web app which is querying a list of loans and loan payments in MySQL. The goal is to display each loan in a table row and then a list of its loan payments in table columns that each represent a sum of loan payments for that day. We also allow the user to select a date range and aggregation level (daily / weekly / monthly). If the user chose Sept 1-3 with daily aggregation, the results would look like this:

```
Loan ID |  sept 1  |  sept 2  |  sept 3
---------------------------------------
0001    |  $350    |  $239.45 |  $112
0002    |  $100    |  $0      |  $75
```

The 2 database tables are Loan and Payment where Payment stores the Loan ID, date, and amount of each payment.

When we run this query on a 60 day range, the result is ~45sec response time. We then tried to create our own pre-aggregated table which was 366 columns per year (Loan ID + daily date columns representing the sum of payments on that day). This increased the response time to > 60sec. That is not even including weekly or monthly aggregation which is even slower.

How can we speed this up? We're ideally looking for 10-15 sec response time, and I have tried every caching / indexing technique I can find without success.

Comment: Update your question and show your tables schema

Comment: You should discuss with the business what are business requirements or practical application of the table with 60 columns?

The result table looks fine for Sep1-3 example, but for 60 days date range? Who would look at this table? You could print payments for specific loan as multiple row report, you could show if someone paid for loans in 60 days period? These results are easy to prepare and readable by actual users.

Answer (score 0):

You should discuss with the business what are business requirements or practical application of the table with 60 columns?

The result table looks fine for Sep1-3 example, but for 60 days date range? Who would look at this table? Would it better to group by weeks or months?

If the number of loans is limited